# Powers of complex numbers : Which is the general formula?

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z=\frac{1}{2}\left (\sqrt{3}+i\right )\in \mathbb{C}$.

I want to calcualte the powers $z^n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I have done the following: \begin{align*}&z^1=\frac{1}{2}\left (\sqrt{3}+i\right ) \\ &z^2=\left (\frac{1}{2}\left (\sqrt{3}+i\right )\right )^2=\frac{1}{4}\left (3+2\sqrt{3}i-1\right )=\frac{1}{4}\left (2+2\sqrt{3}i\right )=\frac{1}{2}\left (1+\sqrt{3}i\right ) \\ &z^3=z^2\cdot z=\frac{1}{2}\left (1+\sqrt{3}i\right )\cdot \frac{1}{2}\left (\sqrt{3}+i\right )=\frac{1}{4}\left (\sqrt{3}+i+3i-\sqrt{3}\right )=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 4i=i \\ & z^4=z^3\cdot z=i\cdot \frac{1}{2}\left (1+\sqrt{3}i\right )=\frac{1}{2}\left (-\sqrt{3}+i\right ) \end{align*} Is therea specific formula that we get for an arbitrary $n$ ?

Comment: Use that $(re^{i\theta})^n=r^ne^{in\theta}.$

Comment: Note $z^{12}=1$ so you can work with $n$ modulo $12$

Comment: $z^n = \cos( \frac{n\pi}{6} ) + \sin( \frac{n\pi}{6} )i$. See [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Comment: Ok! There is also a hint, that $z^3=i$ but I don't really know how this help us. Also we have to draw the powers of $z$, so do we have to draw each power seperately, or is something else meant? @azif00

Comment: Ok! There is also a hint, that $z^3=i$ but I don't really know how this help us. Also we have to draw the powers of $z$, so do we have to draw each power seperately, or is something else meant? @mfl

Comment: So do we have to calculate all powers from $n=1$ till $n=12$ ? @azif00

Comment: Use the hint: If $z^3=i$ then $z^6=(z^3)^2=i^2=-1,$ $z^9=z^6\cdot z^3=-i,$ and $z^{12}=(z^6)^2=(-1)^2=1.$

Comment: Does this mean then that $z$ is period with period $12$ ? @mfl

Comment: Or do we still calculate $z^4, z^5, z^7, z^8, z^{10}, z^{11}$ ? @mfl

Comment: Note that $z^4=iz, z^5=iz^2, z^6=-1, z^7=-z, \cdots$

Comment: Thank you!! :-) @mfl

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to express the general formula using the polar representation of $z = r e^{i\theta}$

$$
z^n = r^n e^{in\theta} = r^n\left(\cos(n\theta) + i \sin(n\theta)\right).
$$

See also [Euler formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) and [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Comment: Ahh, I see!! There is also a hint given, that $z^j=1$,, but I don't if this is emough

Comment: If $z^j = 1$ then $r = 1$, i.e. $z$ lies on the unit circle. In this case, the formula simplifies to $z^n = e^{in\theta} = (\cos(n\theta) + i \sin(n\theta))$. BTW: This has a nice geometric interpretation as a rotation around the origin.

Comment: Oh I meant $z^3=1$ (3 instead of j)

Comment: If $z^3=1$ then $z=1$ or $z=e^{2\pi i / 3}$ or $z=e^{-2\pi i / 3}$. See also [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Comment: Oh I saw now there is a typo, it should be $z^3=i$ not $1$. Can we get from that something about a general power? Or is the polar representation better to use here?